# Pass Key of Grid to Business Class via Object Data Source

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

In ASP.NET Webforms have an ASP.NET GridView connected to a C# class via an object data source

I have an ID set up as a DataKeyName in the grid. How do I pass this to the C# class when I update the grid?

Comment: I haven't used asp.net winforms for a while but, from memory you should be able to get the info from the event args appropriate event

Comment: @Andrew: `asp.net-winforms`?? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually data key names are passed automatically by the datagrid to the object data source.

Answer (score 0):

Can pick up the grids data key name for the current row in the grids row updating event

```
  protected void gvSearchResults_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
    //get handle on current grid row
    DataKey keys = gvSearchResults.DataKeys[e.RowIndex];
   customerId= GeneralUtils.GetIntegerKeyValue(keys, "customerID");
  }
```

Then pass it to C# class using object data sources updating event

```
 protected void odsHauliers_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
  {

    e.InputParameters["customerID"] = this.customerID;
  }
```